# Master-DetailView Application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, master-detail

Im trying to create a Master detail View Application & I'm kinda stuck.

I have a tableView with 100 `DynamicPrototype` `Cells` showing Bars and when i tap on a `cell` i want to present more info about that Bar.

My question is how to fill different `data` like `labels` and `images` into the `DetailView` and change them for each `cell` i tap to represent the correct `data`

My `Detailview` is a `TableViewController` with `StaticCells` as shown here:

[image: Bars My Friends]

I am using Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8.1

I created a class to represent my DetailView Data :

## **BarProfile.Swift:**

```
import Foundation

class BarProfile {
    var HeaderImage = ""
    var HeaderTitle = ""
    var Age = ""
    var Adress = ""
    var Number = ""
    var Time = ""
    var Music = ""
    var Info = ""
    var Menu = ""
    var More = ""
    
    init(HeaderImage: String, HeaderTitle: String, Age: String, Adress: String, Number: String, Time: String, Music: String, Info: String, Menu: String, More: String) {
        
        
        self.HeaderImage = HeaderImage
        self.HeaderTitle = HeaderTitle
        self.Age = Age
        self.Adress = Adress
        self.Number = Number
        self.Time = Time
        self.Music = Music
        self.Info = Info
        self.Menu = Menu
        self.More = More
    
    }
}
```

My `BarsTableView` that looks like this :

[image]

## **BarsTableViewController.Swift:**

```
import UIKit


class BarsTableViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var tableViewController: UITableView!
    
    // MARK : Data

    
    var names = ["Shalvata",
                 "Markid",
                 "Litzman Bar",
                 "The Cat & The Dog",
                 "Light house",

var streets =
    ["האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב",
         "אבן גבירול 30,תל אביב",
        "רחוב נמל תל אביב",
         "קרליבך 28,תל אביב",
         "האנגר 23,נמל תל אביב"]

 var images = [UIImage(named: "Shalvata"),
                  UIImage(named: "Markid"),
                  UIImage(named: "Litzman Bar"),
                  UIImage(named: "CatNDog"),
                  UIImage(named: "LightHouse")]

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 100.5;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        ////////
        
               ////////
    }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        cell.photo.image = user.image
        cell.name.text = user.name
        cell.streetName.text = user.streetName
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("BarsProfile", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

I didn't find a tutorial that shows what I'm really looking for and i was hoping to find the answer here cause detailView is the basic of every project or App .

I don't know how to continue and I'm pretty frustrated about it.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Show the `prepareForSegue` method of whatever class is your master.

Comment: I dont have it yet

Comment: Then you need to do more tutorials, then ask specific questions.  Try: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_8_TableView_Navigation_using_Storyboards_in_Xcode_6_and_Swift

Comment: You've wrote pretty well for a newbie. No worries. See [this moment](https://youtu.be/o_HukQ-IKH8?t=1829) though I suggest your watch the entire video. It's great

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data to the detail view through the `prepareForSegue` function and set variables or call functions in the destination view.

Here's an example of how it could be done. This assumes that the view you use to present 'detail' is of type `DetailView` and the segue from your master -> Detail is called 'BarsProfile':

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "BarsProfile") {
            if(segue.destination is DetailView) {
                let destVC = segue.destination as! DetailView
                // Set variables in Detail View here
                // e.g. :
                destVC.detailData = selectedData
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And if i do this my didselectrow is staying the same?

Comment: I don't understand the question. My understanding is you want to select a row in the table of your 'Master' view, which opens the corresponding 'Detail' view and populates it with information for the selected item. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep. @RicketyRick